# Android Cursor - moveToNext() doesnt seem to go to end of cursor

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

Why doesnt my Android Cursor go all the way to the end of the original "promise"??

My **cursor.getCount()** differs from my last **cursor.getPosition()**. Check my while loop! It is all I do with it!

*Notes*: 
1. it is about querying the Contacts content provider (android api >5)
2. I display only the esential code

```
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(mUri, mProjections, null, null, null);
Logger.d(TAG, "***  cursor.getCount(): "+cursor.getCount());
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Logger.d(TAG, "| position: "+cursor.getPosition());
    processMainCursor(serializer, cursor);
}
cursor.close();
```

processMainCursor() will display data from cursor + do another queries: one 4 phones, one 4 emails, one 4 IM accounts:

```
void processMainCursor(XmlSerializer serializer, Cursor main_cursor) {
     writeCursorData(serializer, main_cursor); //writes cursor data, column by column
     writePhoneEntities(serializer, main_cursor);
     writeEmailEntities(serializer, main_cursor);
     writeIMEntities(serializer, main_cursor);
}
```

In none of my `writeXXX` methods do i close my `main_cursor` or move next!!!..have to trust me on that.. i just do a new query, print data & close that cursor

So statistics:

- cursor.getCount() = 695 (**always**)
- commenting *writePhoneEntities, writeEmailEntities, writeIMEntities*: cursor.getCount() = 
  last cursor.getPosition() = 695 (**so correct!**)
- leaving one/two/all of my *writeXEntities* shows randomness; example: leaving them all: 
  last cursor.getPosition() sometimes displays 254, 257, 253, etc; leaving just phone & IM: 514, 510, 511, etc (**so different RUN -> different last cursor.getPosition() VALUE**)

So oppinions.. Why is that? Is it memory related?

*Update*: 
Leaving any of my writeXEntities displays at the end in logcat:
*Removing dead content provider: contacts*

*Update 2*
Adding  `cursor.moveToFirst();` & doing loop like

```
do {
    //do whatever you want
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

didn't do the job..

So maybe the answer is in this logcat entries:

```
05-21 23:29:30.209: I/ActivityThread(7085): Removing dead content provider: contacts
05-21 23:29:30.209: I/ActivityThread(7085): Removing dead content provider: com.android.contacts
```

**SAMPLE OF a writeXEntity** REMOVED

**SOLUTION** .. i **wasnt** closing the cursors from writeXEntity corectly (probably leaving quite a lot of open cursor after main while)

in reality i was closing like this

```
if(phone_cursor!=null && phone_cursor.getCount() > 0)
{                   
     //... stuff
     phone_cursor.close();
}
```

i should have closed after if

```
if(phone_cursor!=null && phone_cursor.getCount() > 0)
{                   
     //... stuff
}
phone_cursor.close();
```

I guess leaving a basilion cursor open ..was the answer?!?

Comment: Please post one (or all) of your `write` functions, what you have posted should work fine.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it, that way everyone will know that a solution was found (without having ot open the post and read it).

Answer (score 11):

You need to move the cursor to the first row. Try adding `cur.moveToFirst()` before the `while` loop.

You might also consider using a `do-while` loop. This will ensure that you never skip over the first row in the cursor:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        //do whatever you want
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());               
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: According to the author's example: he calls a cursor, prints a statement, and uses `cursor.moveToNext()`.  A new cursor is set to index: -1 and `moveToNext()` will move the index to 0, therefor (_if_ this is all pulancheck does) `moveToFirst()` is not necessary since `moveToNext()` already moves the index to the first row.

Comment: yes sam but why does code print different cursor.getPosition() ..at different RUNs?? (this happens when i have all/some of my writeXEntity uncomented) & what about my last logCat msg "Removing dead content provider"

Comment: @pulancheck1988 My comment here is in response Alex's answer, which I respectfully disagree with given the context. I have no idea why your index is changing, see my comment on your question requesting more code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they won't be the same number as the getCount is the number of items, and the position is the position, ( the first one being 0).  So the final position should always be one less than the count.

If it's something other than that, I guess I'm not understanding your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor as shown below:

```
             if(cursor.getCount() == 0)
              {                   
                 //No entry found
              }
              else  {
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  do {
                     //do whatever you want
                     } while (cursor.moveToNext());               
            cursor.close();
```

Comment: i modified all my cursor looping stuff like you said & result: first RUN- last cursor position: 257, second RUN: 256 ..so still hadn't reached my promised 695.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answer you already found (problem with closing cursors) I think that the best way to ensure you close them all is with this code:

```
Cursor c = null;
try {
   c = <your query>;
   if (c.moveToFirst()) { // No point in doing more if empty.
      do {
         <process this cursor row>
      } while (c.moveToNext());
   }
}
finally {
   if (c != null) c.close(); // Not sure the check needed, maybe if query was really wrong.
}
```